# Tinymce отправляет только со второго раза

Tags: ajax, tinymce

Отправляю форму *AJAX*, на `textarea` навесил `tinymce`, изменения значений в `input` отправляются с первого раза при сохранении. А из `textarea` только при повторной отправки формы. Если убрать с `textarea tinymce`, то отрабатывает все нормально.

В чем может быть проблема?

**Отправка**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#forma').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    var $that = $(this),
    formData = new FormData($that.get(0)); // создаем новый экземпляр объекта и передаем ему нашу форму (*)
    $.ajax({
      url: $that.attr('action'),
      type: $that.attr('method'),
      contentType: false, // важно - убираем форматирование данных по умолчанию
      processData: false, // важно - убираем преобразование строк по умолчанию
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(res){
        if(res){
        $('.answer_forma').html('');
            if(res['error'] != ''){
                $('.answer_forma').append(res['error'])
            }else{
                $('.answer_forma').append(res['success'])
            }
            console.log(res) 
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Инициализация tinymce**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    tinymce.init({
    selector: '.redactor_mini',
    language: 'ru',
    height: 300,
    theme: 'modern',
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime contextmenu'
      ],
          toolbar1: 'formatselect bold italic forecolor backcolor link alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify numlist bullist removeformat ',
    image_advtab: true,
    powerpaste_allow_local_images: true,
    paste_retain_style_properties: "font-family",
    content_css: [
      '/admin/templates/css/tinymce.css'
    ]
   });
});
```

**Форма**

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="forma" enctype="multipart/form-data">              
    <div class="answer_forma"></div>
    <div class="panel_body">
        <div class="input_list">
            <label>Название</label>
            <input type="text" name="save_arr[name]" value="" />
        </div>
        <div class="input_list">
            <label>Текст</label>
            <textarea class="input_edit text_left redactor_mini" name="save_arr[text]"></textarea>
        </div>                    
        <button type="submit" name="save" class="button_normal">Сохранить</button>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinyMCE хранит редактируемый текст отдельно. Видимо при отправке формы редактор не успевает синхронизировать текст с textarea. (обычно синхронизируется, когда фокус покидает редактор, если находясь в редакторе нажимаете кнопку сабмита, то сабмит происходит раньше)

Чтобы наверняка получить текст при отправке, сделайте

```
formData = new FormData($that.get(0));
var editor = tinyMCE.EditorManager.get('id редактора');
formData.set('save_arr[text]', editor.getContent());
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! Все прекрасно отработало!